# too many values error from sql

Tags: sql, oracle

member{ID,PASS,NAME,AGE,GENDER,EMAIL,SYSDATE}
LOGINLOG{ID,SYS}

I want to make sure exclude all the previous loginlog datas

```
 select
  to_char(ll.SYS),
  mm.ID,
  count(*)
from 
    member mm, 
    loginlog ll 
where 
    mm.ID=ll.ID  
    and (
         (select 
                to_char(l.SYS),
                m.ID,
                count(*) 
                from member m , loginlog l
            where  l.ID = m.ID group by(to_char(l.SYS) , m.ID)
          ) != all(select to_char(ls.SYS), ls.ID ,ls.NUM from loginsave ls)
      ) 
group by(to_char(ll.SYS),mm.ID);
```

this gives an "

```
ORA-00913: too many values
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"
*Cause:    
*Action:
11, 11 column error
```

Comment: Oracle errors come from Oracle, not MySQL.  Provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clearly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
select to_char(ll.SYS), mm.ID, count(*)
from member mm join
     loginlog ll 
     on mm.ID = ll.ID  
group by to_char(ll.SYS), mm.ID
having (to_char(ll.SYS), mm.ID, count(*)) not in
           (select to_char(ls.SYS), ls.ID, ls.NUM from loginsave ls);
```

Comment: yes, sir can you tell me why my code is not working>?

Comment: There are multiple reasons.  But one important one is that your condition with the subquery has no reference to the rows in the outer `select`.

Comment: select to_char(l.SYS),l.ID,count(*) 
from member l , loginlog lg  where lg.ID = l.ID group by (to_char(l.SYS),l.ID)
minus
select to_char(ls.SYS),ls.ID,ls.num  from loginsave ls;